# Managing Data Driven Pages with ArcObjects

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, data-driven-pages

I can't find any resources on managing Data Driven Pages with ArcObjects. E.g.: is it possible to use ArcObjects (.NET) for the following tasks:

1. Check if the current map document has enabled Data Driven Pages?
2. Loop through all pages and get the name, number, extent and scale of each page?
3. Enable DPP and set the index layer?
4. Disable DPP?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000p07000000

I've used Python, not ArcObjects for this, but looks like you are limited to the interfaces, IPrintAndExport and IPageIndexControl, could be more....

And the methods with Python scripting are recommended:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000001z1000000

Comment: Thanks. I've looked at the IPrintAndExport and IPageIndexControl. If that would be all I'd be really disappointed. An alternative could be to identify the page index feature class and check its attributes...

Answer (score 2):

[This ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087E00000004s1FIAQ) hints that data driven page functionality is not exposed in ArcObjects other than the `IPrintAndExport` interface.